# EPUB validation, specifications needed

Tags: epub

Hi Please help to solve my problem. I have a problem with "Pagina EPUB-Checker" when I have try to validate my epub file the checker was not showing error details only its showing "epubcheck finished with error or warnings". Please see the screen shot and help me to fix this problem. The same file working in other online validation. but not in this tool.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkP44.png)

Comment: What did you validate?

Comment: Creator of "pagina EPUB-Checker" here. What messages did you get in the online validator?